# Ternary Operators for else if

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I want to convert this to ternary operator so I can simplify my codes..

```
<?php
  $checked = $value['chkboxvalue'] == 'ok' ? 'checked' : '';
  if(isset($_POST['chckbox'])):
      $checked = 'checked';
   elseif(count($_POST) > 0):
      $checked = "";
   endif;
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="chckbox" value="ok" <?=$checked?> />
```

and I tried this way.

```
<?php
$checked = $value['chckboxvalue'] == 'ok' ? 'checked' : '';
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="chckbox" value="ok" class="checkbox" <?=isset($_POST['chckbox']) ? 'checked' : (count($_POST) > 0 ? '' : 'checked')?> />
```

But it's not working :( any help? Thanks!

Comment: Explain "not working" in terms of the actual HTML output you receive. Nested ternary conditions also aren't widely considered to make code more readable; utility functions do.

Comment: `$checked = ($value['chkboxvalue'] == 'ok') ? 'checked' : '';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `count` function is not closed correctly and instead of last `'checked'` hardcoded value use `$checked` variable, try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chckbox" value="ok" class="checkbox" <?= isset($_POST['chckbox']) ? 'checked' : (count($_POST)) > 0 ? '' : $checked ?> />
```

Comment: Instead of last `'checked'` hardcoded value use `$checked` variable, answer updated try updated code

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for ternary operation is wrong! Use this way:

```
$checked = ($value['chckboxvalue'] == 'ok') ? 'checked' : '';
```

And if you need to add an `elseif` condition, do this way:

```
$checked = ($value['chckboxvalue'] == 'ok') ? ((count($_POST) > 0) ? 'checked' : '') : '';
```